# static routes and user validation in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to do the following.

1. all / requests should server files from /public folder. (e.g. http://my.host/docu/index.html -> /public/docu/index.html)
2. if the user is not authorized it should be redirected to "oauth/login" route

here what I tried sofar.. but it doesn't work as expected:

```
var staticMiddlewarePrivate = express['static'](__dirname + '/public');

app.use(/^\/(?!oauth).*/, function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user == null) {
        console.log("doing redirect as not login");
        res.redirect('/oauth/login');
        return;
    }
    console.log("user logged in");
    staticMiddlewarePrivate(req, res, next);
});
```

how could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

the trick was to put static route after dynamic:

```
app.use(/^\/(?!oauth).*/, function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.user == null) {
        console.log("doing redirect as not login");
        res.redirect('/oauth/login');
        return;
    }
    console.log("user logged in");
    next()
});
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public') );
```